# 0 and 1 in custom dimension Google analytics VWO?

Tags: google-analytics, vwo

I am A/B testing with Visual Website optimizer and have manually added code to send info to a custom dimension in GA.

This works fine, but there is one issue... in the custom dimension I get the names of the Variations that i specified but also "0" and "1" who both have around 100% conversion rate.... Has someone else encountered this issue or knows where i might find "the problem"?

I have tried to find a solution online and on stack overflow but i can't find an answer....

Comment: Can you post screenshots of what you're seeing? Also please post your relevant code, too.

Comment: I think the client was pushing other data to the dimension as well, will know if thats the case tomorrow. Thanks for responding so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

There was other data being sent by another service as well... Not certain yet if it has a negative effect on the a/b- test data

Answer (score 0):

If you are funneling data into a custom dimension, create a custom report and filter the matching regex of the category or action you send. Then you don't have to worry about other data funneling in to the same dimension.